# Make windows route al traffic to one IP to another

Tags: windows, networking, routing, windows-server-2008-r2

i have a Windows 2008 server that needs to connect to an IP that its hardcodded in a application. 
Instead of referencing \localhost it references \OldPrivateIp
The Machine cannot change Subnet(Security issue).

So i need the request to everytime they request \OldPrivateIp\SharedFolder they go to \NewPrivateIp\SharedFolder

Comment: you cannot, at least not with routing tools. you can route 'through' another IP, but you can't just replace one with another, unless another piece of software is mangling the IP ( like a sophisticated firewall  or proxy). you can mangle name-to-IP mappings, but that won;t help you, Why don;t you just add the old IP to the new box's nic (or add a new nic if its on another network) so it can be reached either by new or old?

Comment: Because that IP, is part of another network running in our environment. And due to the security certification needed this machine cant be in that subnet. No other michine in that subnet uses that IP, but if wasnt for that security certification it cant be used.

Comment: you are saying "instead of \localhost", so is that share on the same machine as the application with the hardcoded IP? is it a physical machine or virtual? If it is the same machine, you could put in a NIC without any network cable and give it the required IP. Maybe in that case you need to do some routing if that machine has to be able to reach the real subnet with that IP range.

Comment: Its an AzureVM with a custom VM